# ExceptionInInitializerError Android NDK Caused by: UnsatisfiedLinkError: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I am using NDK support in my app and am loading library like this:

```
 static {
     System.loadLibrary("sensorgraph");
 }
```

All the native methods in **sensorgraph.cpp** starts with package name and JNI Activity name, like:

```
 Java_sensor_com_ms_android_knowursensor_controller_jni_SensorGraphJNI_init(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jobject assetManager) {
        (void)type;
        AAssetManager *nativeAssetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
        gSensorGraph.init(nativeAssetManager);
    }
```

I am getting `ExceptionInInitializerError` on running the app.

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1042
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at sensor.com.ms.android.knowursensor.ui.view.AccelGLSV$2.run(AccelGLSV.java:58)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1470)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sensorgraph from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.ms.android.knowursensor-41.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.ms.android.knowursensor-41]: findLibrary returned null
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
 at sensor.com.ms.android.knowursensor.controller.jni.SensorGraphJNI.<clinit>(SensorGraphJNI.java:26)
 at sensor.com.ms.android.knowursensor.ui.view.AccelGLSV$2.run(AccelGLSV.java:58) 
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1470) 
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

I have tried all answers from SO, however no solution is correct. Please help.

Comment: The ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown when the JVM attempts to load a new class. During the class loading procedure, all static variables and static initializers are being evaluated. A static initializer is a block enclosed within curly braces without having any name and return type, except having the keyword static.http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Comment: @AmarbirSingh Thanks, but what is causing the Exception here?

Comment: I think this is because of your library you are using "findLibrary returned null"

Answer (score 1):

1. No proper shared library-----Your device is arm type,but you build x86 type shared library.
2. No proper function found-----You may try hello-jni in NDK sample folder first.
3. Failed to copy shared library when package is installing--------You can try [KeepSafe/ReLinker](https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker)

Comment: Thanks, i am using CPP file (sensorgraph.cpp) and i have placed it in jni folder. Still it does not compile.